# Passport's Local-Signup strategy tries to save new user twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, passport.js

I find the Passport documentation really baffling because it seems to try to illustrate by code examples without actually explaining what's going on or how the various callbacks relate to each other. My issue is that while signups *work*, they always run twice (which crashes the application due to the unique constraint on usernames), and I can't find any description of Passport's program flow that would help me figure out where or why this is happening.

My full Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/jennygreene88/c6c88ccecb7912356c684daddb276d02), sloppy because I've spent all night trying to solve this and refactored into madness. I moved it to TypeScript hoping the additional info would help me.

My design is basically:

- `GET /signup` displays a simple form that POSTs a username and password to `/signup`
- `POST /signup` calls the `local-signup` strategy, redirecting to `/` on success or `/signup` on failure
- The local-signup strategy finds a username from the DB, and if no username is found, inserts one, and calls `done(null, {username, id, bcryptPassword})`.

Comment: Why don't you just post your code instead of _describing_ it? Cause all we can do is describe a solution like "Fix the faulty function"

Comment: I linked the code in the second paragraph. I didn't paste it here because it was too long, and I don't really trust my understanding enough to trim it down.

Comment: Ah, right, so why are you describing it then? :) And it's always better to post code in the question instead of an external link

Comment: Okay, a few new questions then : 1. Why are you only finding a user by its username and not its password? This means any password is valid. 2. In case the username is not found, a new user is created. This means every time someone makes a typo in their username, you create a new user? As a sidenote, I also find Passport overly complicated.

Comment: It's not finding user only by username -- it finds a username, then checks the password, and rejects if it doesn't match the hashed supplied one (line 23). A new user is only created if the username isn't found on the signup route -- if it's not found on the login route, it just fails to log in.